# Updating a spring database from a react switch element

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

I have a list of users and their account status as a table in my react js application. This table entry is fetched from an API call. Now when I click on a button, the value of account status has to be updated in the database. The endpoint is working fine and I've tested it also.

I've created a button for each user to update the database. It's currently not updating the value in the database.

React Material UI code :-

```
<TableBody>
                {items.map(item => (
                      <TableRow key={item.username}>
                        <TableCell component="th" scope="item">
                          {item.username}
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell>
                        <Button onClick={this.onItemClick} variant="contained">
                          Update Status
                        </Button>
                        </TableCell>
                      </TableRow>
                ))}
              </TableBody>
```

the onItemClick handler has to make an API Call and update the database value accordingly.
Kindly provide some help regarding the approach to be followed. Thank you

Comment: It is not clear what is working and what is not from your description. When you click on the button you need to send request to API, if you can provide some fragments of your code which doesnt work then someone can help you.

Comment: nearly default answer for 1st time posters: please provide more informations like code or error messages.

Comment: @MikhailChibel I've added the code snippet

Comment: @Marc I've added the code snippet. Do check it out.

Comment: @cyberman123 how do you fetch the table entry from the API? As you said yourself, you need to call API within the onItemClick() method. I don't understand what is the problem here.